# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.0', apply: false] Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola actualice el Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3

Tengo el siguiente error al iniciar el proyecto

```
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\SanLucasApp\build.gradle.kts' line: 7

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.2.0')
```

Aqui mi archivos

build.grandle.kts

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false
}
```

settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "SanLucasApp"
include(":app")
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

He leido es un error bien comun, pero no puedo solucionarlo
Me recomienda,borrar una carpeta, desintalar el android studio y volver a instararlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la versión de android studio, usa de forma predeterminada una versión de plugin gradle o distribución de gradle determinada, a su vez una versión determinada de Java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso si usas la versión 7.2.0 en algún recurso de tu proyecto, te sugiero cambiar la versión de Java a 1.8

ve a:
File > Project Structure > SDK Location > y cambia la versión de Java a 1.8 donde indico en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]